# way to get a percentage of change history using git-tf

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs, git-tf

I am using git-tf to migrate my project from tfs to git. The problem is that its a massive project with 20k+ commits and the socket connection closes after 7-8 hours of migration giving me the following error :

> git-tf: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Read timed out

I am wondering if there's a way of just migrating a recent percentage of change history instead of the full set. E.g- something like

> git-tf clone http://tfs2012.xxx:8080/TFS/DefaultCollection/
>   $/"xxx" --deep '30%'

which shall pick up only 30 % of recent commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can specify the `--deep <count>` argument to indicate the number of changesets to download.

For example:

```
git tf clone --depth 10 https://visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection $/Project/Folder
```

To download only the most recent 10 changesets.

See `git tf help clone` for more information.